# Strip html tags - lxml.html.clean.clean_html doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, lxml

I want to strip all html tags from a string except some I specify.
If I call the constructor with default values everything works fine:

```
>>> cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner()
>>> cleaner.clean_html('''<i>italic</i><script>alert('');</script>''')
'<span><i>italic</i></span>'
```

But when I try to specify some tags, things doesn't work anymore:

```
>>> allowed_tags = ['i','s']
>>> cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(remove_unknown_tags=False,allow_tags=allowed_tags)
>>> cleaner.clean_html('''<i>italic</i><s>strike</s>''')
'<span></span>'
```

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can add `span` and `div` tags to `allowed_tags`.

**UPD**

`lxml.html.Cleaner`  [tries to convert](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/clean.py#L495) string to html tree by calling [fromstring](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/__init__.py#L643), which checks if document have some root node, and adds it if necessary. So you need to allow [`span` and `div` tags](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/__init__.py#L702)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug. I don't see it in `lxml==2.3.3` version:

```
>>> from lxml.html import clean
>>> clean.clean_html('''<i>italic</i><script>alert('');</script>''')
'<span><i>italic</i></span>'
>>> c = clean.Cleaner(allow_tags='is', remove_unknown_tags=False)
>>> c.clean_html('''<i>italic</i><s>strike</s>''')
'<div><i>italic</i><s>strike</s></div>'
```